# Добавление ссылки в открывающееся изображения Fancybox

Tags: javascript, html5, fancybox

Добрый день. Суть вопроса такова. Использую Fancybox для галлереи изображений. Но вот столкнулся с такой проблемой. Необходимо добавить на открывшуюся копию изображения(увеличенная) в подписи (берётся из title) ссылку с переходом на всю коллекцию изображений. В моём случает в галлереи свыше 160 изображений миниатюр, а коллекций всего 38. Пример желаемой реализации хочу как на [этом](http://www.erismann.de/de/produkte/wohnwelten) сайте сделать. Есть миниатюра, по клику открывается большая копия, а в ней есть кнопка "перейти на коллекцию". Но в fancybox походу так нельзя. Кто сталкивался с такой проблемой и нашёл её устранение?

Comment: покажите  js код вызова галереи

Comment: Спасибо, уже разобрался в чём была загвоздка. Уже и реализовал))